# check if array is ordered subset postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subset

how to check if an array is an ordered subset of another array in PostgreSQL?

```
[1, 2] ordered_subset [1, 4, 2] -> true
[1, 2] ordered_subset [2, 3, 1, 5] -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter out elements from the second array that do not belong to the first, and then check if the first is a subarray of the second by using `generate_series`:

```
select exists (select 1 from generate_series(1, array_length(t1.a3, 1)) v2 
       where t1.a1 = t1.a3[v2:v2+array_length(t1.a1, 1)-1]) from 
   (select t.a1, (select array_agg(v) from unnest(t.a2) v 
         where exists (select 1 from unnest(t.a1) v1 where v1 = v)) a3
    from array_inp t
) t1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7KWjRMsx).